# Can you acquire an infection by inhaling bacteria and viruses?

Tags: infection, fever, inhalation, nostrils

I am not medical student so you may feel this is silly. But is this possible?

Can you acquire an infection by inhaling bacteria and viruses?

Comment: Typing those exact three words in google "inhaling bacteria and viruses" brings up your answer.

Comment: Also, try to give your questions a more elaborate title next time. It would help to direct the right people to answer your question.